# Compactness of the inverse Laplacian.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded *regular* open set. Let $\Delta^{-1}:L^2(\Omega)\to H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$ be the (weak) inverse Laplace operator. By the Lax-Milgram theorem, we know that $\Delta^{-1}$ is an isomorphism, and by regularity results we also know that it is continuous. Now if we look at the following operator:
$$T:L^2(\Omega)\overset{\Delta^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} H^1_0(\Omega)\overset{i}{\hookrightarrow} L^2(\Omega), $$
then $T$ is continuous and compact since the Sobolev embedding $i$ is continuous, and it is compact by Rellich-Kondrachov. How can we deduce from this $\Delta^{-1}$ is compact? Or is there another way to show that $\Delta^{-1}$ is compact? It seems I'm missing something obvious here!

Comment: The composition of a bounded operator with a compact one is again compact.

Comment: Yes, $T=i\circ\Delta^{-1}$ is compact, but what about $\Delta^{-1}$ alone?

Comment: The point is that $\Delta^{-1}$ is continuous from $L^2(\Omega)$ to $H_0^1(\Omega)$, and the inclusion in the reverse order is compact by Rellich, so their composition is compact. We might say from here that it is compact on $L^2$ (although we're really talking about the restriction).

Comment: @cmk and is the restriction compact?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $L^2(\Omega)$ is infinite-dimensional,
the isomorphism $\Delta^{-1} \colon L^2(\Omega) \to H_0^1(\Omega) \cap H^2(\Omega)$ can never be compact.
Indeed, if $\Delta^{-1}$ would be compact,
the identity $\operatorname{id} = \Delta \colon \Delta^{-1}$ on $L^2(\Omega)$ would be compact.

Comment: What about $(I-\Delta)^{-1}:L^2(\Omega)\to H^1_0(\Omega)$? Is this compact?

Comment: Yes, because here, you can use the compactness of the embedding of $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: Because $(I-\Delta)^{-1} : H^{-1}(\Omega) \to H_0^1(\Omega)$ is continuous. The concatenation of a bounded and a compact operator is compact.